# How to save multiple p:rating values from p:dataTable into database using JSF?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I am using JSF 2.2 and primefaces. I have a database table in which one field of type STRING consisting of multiple questions combined using comma.i have retrieved the field and converted the whole string into a arraylist and stored as abc in myBeanController.the list is displayed using dataTable.i want to save the individual abc list item along with its corresponding rating value in database new table.The jsf code for displaying is as shown below.

```
<p:dataTable var="list1" value="#{myBeanController.abc}">                      

    <p:column width="60%" >
                  <h:outputText id="saqs" value="#{list1}" />                
            </p:column>

             <p:column width="60%"  >
                  <p:rating stars="4" cancel="false" value="#{myBeanController.rating}"/>
             </p:column>
     </p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways, but I think the most easy is not to use a `List<String>` for `abc` property, but instead a list of a class that allows you to hold both: string and rating.

I mean the following:

```
public class Question{
  private String question = null;
  private Integer rating = null;

  //Other stuff, accessors/mutator, and so on
}
```

Then, in your back bean you change your question's string in a `List<Question>`, and change your render to:

```
<p:dataTable var="list1" value="#{myBeanController.abc}">                      

    <p:column width="60%" >
        <h:outputText id="saqs" value="#{list1.question}" />                
    </p:column>

    <p:column width="60%"  >
         <p:rating stars="4" cancel="false" value="#{list1.rating}"/>
    </p:column>
 </p:dataTable>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: hi, thanks for reply. But we have saved multiple questions as a string and saved in database. In order to display them we are converting them as Arraylist. Just help us how to write Backing bean to save the item of arraylist with its respective rating

Comment: Well I am not telling you that you have to change how you persist your questions. I only suggest you, how to transform your question's string into a different structure to represent them in view layer. Once you have rating values, you can do what you want with them. I don't say anything about changing how you represent your questions, so my answer is fully compatible with your already stored questions. It is a matter of representation.